# Angular2 and Kendoui with custom filtering in grid

Tags: angular, user-interface, kendo-ui

I have created on grid layout.
but when i created some custom filter i used "import { CompositeFilterDescriptor } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';" class so when i'm compiling it it shows warning as below.

WARNING in ./src/app/dropdownfilter.component.ts
60:95-120 "export 'CompositeFilterDescriptor' was not found in '@progress/kendo-data-query'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6pi0.png)

so can you give npm installer package which contains CompositeFilterDescriptor..

Comment: That is just warning, can your app actually run?

Comment: @wannadream it didn't show **anything** in browser

Comment: any errors from browser console?

Comment: only these warning is shown @wannadream and it shows nothing also not loading.. test

Comment: This is difficult to debug. I would recommend you to reinstall KendoUI packages.

Comment: ive had the same issue for a couple of weeks, my app runs fine without it but i believe the warning is displaying even when it shouldnt

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there are issues with Typescript or Webpack that are best explained here..

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034#issuecomment-286733947
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034#issuecomment-302666897

TLDR; TS interfaces are abstract and vaporize once compiled into JS, but in newer versions of JS (i.e. ES6) interfaces are supported and so WebPack expects to find them commonJS modules.

The way I got around it (for now) is to infer the type, as opposed to declaring it directly..

This works..

```
@Input() public filter = <CompositeFilterDescriptor>null;
```

This gives an error..

```
@Input() public filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor = null;
```